# Animation is not called CSS

Tags: css

When we press a key, the dino gets a jump class that should trigger an animation. However, the animation is not called.

[animation doesn't run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKbkq.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Dino game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="game">
            <div id="dino"></div>
            <div id="cactus"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
const dino = document.getElementById("dino");
const cactus = document.getElementById("cactus");


document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    jump();
});

function jump() {
    if (dino.classList != "jump") {
        dino.classList.add("jump");
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        dino.classList.remove("jump");
    }, 300)
}
```

```
.game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#dino {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(/image/dino/run1.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    animation: run 0.3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes run {
    0% {
        background-image: url(/image/dino/run1.png);
    }

    50% {
        background-image: url(/image/dino/run2.png);
    }

    100% {
        background-image: url(/image/dino/run3.png);
    }
}

#cactus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(/image/cactus/cactus.png);
    background-size: 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 580px;
    animation: cactusMov 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes cactusMov {
    0% {
        left: 580px;
    }
    100% {
        left: -20px;
    }
}

.jump {
    animation: jump 0.3s linear;
}

@keyframes jump {
    0% {
        top: 150px;
    }
    30% {
        top: 130px;
    }
    50% {
        top: 180px;
    }
    80% {
        top: 130px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 150px;
    }
}
```

I checked, the function and condition are triggered, the class is added to the dino, but the animation still doesn't work.
I'm trying to get the jump animation to start when any key is pressed.

Comment: Look up CSS selectivity. The #dino setting which has animation run takes precedence over class jump.

Comment: Don't use `classList != "something"` use rather: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains

Comment: Also, make sure to use clearTimeout as well - or another approach overall. I'm also not sure how you're planning to implement a proper game without collision detection, by only animating using CSS...

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`

Comment: @Rob Thank you. I know. Prettier did it for me and I didn't notice.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thank you. Why should I use contains instead of classList != "something"?

Answer (score -2):

Make the following change in your CSS:

```
    #dino.jump {
      animation: jump 0.3s linear;
    }
```